# firefox content heights different from safari/chrome

Tags: html, css, firefox

I am setting the min-height  for content on a page (using a pixel value, not a percentage) so I can line up an absolute-positioned image at the bottom of the content. It works correctly in chrome and safari, but in Firefox, the height renders differently and I can't figure out why. On some pages this tactic works perfectly across all browsers, on others it does not.

Here is a sample page:
http://summershortsfestival.com/staging/newsite/past-festivals-2011.php

I am using a reset CSS and normalize to try and fix any differences in how the browsers render content.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is same on chorme or firefox where exactly is the problem?

Comment: what is your Firefox version?

Comment: Everything aligned correctly in safari and chrome, firefox was the issue. I was using version 25.0.1, so the most up-to-date.

Answer (score 1):

You can use vendor prefixes such as -moz- for firefox. If ever ou are using an older version of any browsers, you might want to add modernizr.js as a plugin so it can read current tags. You can download it [here](http://modernizr.com/).

Comment: Thank you, XtianDev. I will check out modernizr. I actually found a fix by creating a new container div and making the image the background no-repeat with bottom positioning. This worked better anyhow, as I didn't have to set specific page heights for the container on each page, it just always placed the image at the bottom, flush with the footer.